# como configurar um componente drawer para que ela empurre todo o conteúdo do site para o lado e ainda não seja afetada pelo scroll?

Tags: css, react, material-ui

A ideia era empurrar todos os outros conteúdo da outra Box para a direita quando o drawer estivesse, porem ele fosse imune ao scroll do mouse deixando o conteúdo dela sempre visivel

```
  <Box>
    <Sidebar onClose={(data) => {
      setOpen(data);
    }} open={open} />
  </Box>

  <Box>
    <Navbar onOpen={(data) => {
      setOpen(data);
    }} />

    <Perfil />
    <AboutMe />
    <DevSkills />
    <Services />
    <Experience />
    <Qualificacoes />
    <Footer />
  </Box>

</Box>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]